# How to translate this definition about ranked alphabets into pure mathematical notation?

Tags: notation, definition, trees, automata

Given [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.02036.pdf) definition:

> **Definition 2.1.** An alphabet $\Sigma$ is said to be ranked if for each nonnegative integer $k$ a subset $\Sigma_k$ of $\Sigma$ is specified, such that $\Sigma_k$ is nonempty for a finite number of $k$'s only, and such that $\Sigma= \bigcup_{k \ge 0} \Sigma_k$. $^\dagger$

How would you write that more formally using things like $\forall k \in \mathbb{N},\dots$? I am having a hard time seeing how to turn this into a more formalized version which I could then figure out how to translate into something like Coq.

Comment: $\text{Ranked}(S) \leftrightarrow \exists N \forall k  \ [k < N \to \exists S_k (S_k \subseteq S \land S_k \ne \emptyset \land S= \bigcup_k S_k)]$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA can it be more specific, such as telling you that you increment the `k` by one each time?

Comment: Not necessarily... but if you know that the  $k$ are a finite number, for sure there is an N large enough such that, form that point on, all $S_k$ are empty.

Comment: The real question is probably not if you can, but if you should. What's the context?

Comment: You should check that the union over $\,k\,$ is probably supposed to be a **disjoint** union. In that case, it would be easier to specify the rank function, $\,r:\Sigma\to\mathbb{N}.$

Comment: [Follow up question](https://www.quora.com/unanswered/What-can-you-do-with-a-mathematical-logic-expression-such-as-Ranked-%25F0%259D%2591%2586-%25F0%259D%2591%2581-%25F0%259D%2591%2598-%25F0%259D%2591%2598-%25F0%259D%2591%2581-%25F0%259D%2591%2586%25F0%259D%2591%2598-%25F0%259D%2591%2586%25F0%259D%2591%2598-%25F0%259D%2591%2586). I am basically interested in modeling mathematical expressions like this in code (which I've now done some examples like this for). Now I want to see how to _apply_ it, can I use such an expression AST for formal verification somehow? Or must I add computability?